# react rendering html for smaller screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I am trying to develop a responsive design.
- right now for smaller screens this console is printing. `console.log("resize--->", window.innerWidth);`
- where as this div is not printing.
- i am calling resize method in render but still its not working.
  `this.resize();`
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my sandbox and code snippet below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-4gnt3

```
resize() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 760) {
      console.log("resize--->", window.innerWidth);

      return (
        <div>
          jkdfjkdfjkdf jdfkljkdfjkdfjk jkdfjkdfjkdfjk jkjkjkjk jkjkjkjk klklklkl
          klklklk klklklkl klklklkl klklklkl klklklkl klklklkl klklklkl klklklkl
          I am here
        </div>
      );
    }
    // this.setState({ hideNav: window.innerWidth <= 760 });
  }
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const bull = <span className={classes.bullet}>•</span>;
    {
      this.resize();
    }
```

}

Comment: is there a reason  why you can't use css for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored your example a little bit, and it works for me.  Link below:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-c7xzb

The changes I made were:

- wrapped everything you're returning in a `div`
- moved your conditional div inside your render's `return` method (nothing else will get shown on screen)
- changed your `console.log`s in `showDiv`, but that probably doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Use the internal react state to control showing the element like below:

```js
resize() {
  if (window.innerWidth <= 760) {
    this.setState({ showDiv: true });
  } else {
    this.setState({ showDiv: false });
  }
}

render() {
  return (
  <Card className={classes.card}>
    {this.state.showDiv && <div>jkdfjkdfjkdf...</div>}
  </Card>
  );
 
}
```

Comment: hey I updated your code in sandbox  but still I dont see it for smaller screens :( https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-4gnt3

Comment: You need to return it in the render method.  I just updated my code to show an example.